Why does the harmonic mean appear in this triangle problem?
Here is the geometry problem where the answer involves the harmonic mean:

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$ and $P$ and $Q$ are on the sides $AB$
and $AC$ respectively. If $AQ/AC=m$ and $AP/AB=n$. Find $AN/AM$.


I solved it using the ratio of area of the triangles. From the Sine Rule we have, $$\dfrac{\text{Area}{\triangle APQ}}{\text{Area}{\triangle ABC}}=\dfrac{AP.AQ}{AB.AC}=mn$$
Let $\text{Area}{\triangle ABC}=S$, we have $\text{Area}{\triangle ACM}=\text{Area}{\triangle ABM}=S/2$. Now let $AN/AM=x$, similarly we have:
$$\dfrac{\text{Area}{\triangle ANQ}}{\text{Area}{\triangle AMC}}=mx\quad, \quad \dfrac{\text{Area}{\triangle APN}}{\text{Area}{\triangle ABM}}=nx$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{\text{Area}{\triangle APQ}}{S/2}=(m+n)x\Rightarrow \dfrac{\text{Area}{\triangle APQ}}{\text{Area}{\triangle ABC}}=\dfrac{(m+n)x}2$$
Now we have $\dfrac{(m+n)x}{2}= mn$, which implies that $\color{red}{x=\dfrac{2mn}{m+n}}$. It means that the ratio $AN/AM$ is the harmonic mean of the ratios $AQ/AC$ and $AP/AB$.
I'm wondering why the harmonic mean appears in this problem and if it is possible to solve this problem differently to make it more intuitive to understand why harmonic mean appears.

Whenever a harmonic mean appears, there's usually an arithmetic mean lurking nearby. Here, it comes from the word "midpoint." Here's a different proof which makes it clear why the harmonic mean shows up.
Assign coordinates to the problem in such a way that $A=(0,0)$ and line $PQ$ is the line $y=1$. Points $B$ and $C$ have $y$-coordinates $\frac{AB}{AP}=\frac1n$ and $\frac{AC}{AQ}=\frac1m$. Therefore the $y$-coordinate of $M$ is
$$\frac{\frac1n+\frac1m}2.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{AN}{AM}=\left(\frac{AM}{AN}\right)^{-1}=\frac1{\frac{\frac1n+\frac1m}2}=\frac{2mn}{m+n}.$$

Thanks for the interesting answer. I realized that the proof is valid for the case that $PQ$ is on $y=q$ (as $q$ is going to be simplified in the calculations) so the distance from the x-axis is not a problem. However, I don't know how to generalize the proof when $PQ$ is not parallel to the x-axis.

@User You're allowed to pick the coordinate system. So, you can choose your coordinates in such a way that $A=(0,0)$ (by translating the diagram so that $A$ and $(0,0)$ coincide), and then rotate your coordinate system so that $PQ$ is parallel to the $x$-axis. (I've also scaled the problem so that this line is given by $y=1$, since the property of the problem ("one length ratio is the harmonic mean of these two other length ratios") is invariant under scaling, but as you've noticed this is not really necessary.)

@Carl Schildkraut I have given a proof using another kind of coordinates.

Having ratios like $AQ/AC, AP/AB, AN/AM$ is for me a natural invitation to use barycentric coordinates (abbreviation b.c.).
Indeed, with your notations, the b.c. of $Q$, $P$ and $N$ are :
$$\begin{cases}(1a)&Q=[1-m;0,m],\\(1b)&P=[1-n;n;0],\\(1c)&N=[1-x;\tfrac{x}{2};\tfrac{x}{2}]\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
See a proof of (1c) in the Appendix below.
Now let us express that $Q,P,N$ are aligned by writing that the determinant of their b.c. is zero :
$$\det \pmatrix{1-m&1-n&1-x\\0&n&\tfrac{x}{2}\\m&0&\tfrac{x}{2}}=0\tag{2}$$
Expanding (1)  gives :
$$x=\frac{2mn}{m+n}$$
as desired.
Appendix : Proof of (1c)
$$\frac{AN}{AM}=x \ \iff \ N-A=x(M-A)$$
$$\iff \ N=A+x\left(\tfrac12(B+C)-A\right)$$
$$\iff \ N=\underbrace{(1-x) \ }_aA+\underbrace{\tfrac{x}{2}}_bB+\underbrace{\tfrac{x}{2}}_cC$$
Sanity check : the second and third b.c. of $N$ are indeed equal because $N$ belongs to the median issued from $A$.
(b.c. (1a) and (1b) can be established in the same way).

Any comment ?...
